# How to handle _googleSignIn.disconnect() (Google Sign Out) in a separate Page in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-signin

I have used [google_sign_in 3.2.1][1], Google Sign In and Sign out work when they are on the same page (same class). Could someone explain how to move the Sign out functionality to a different page (having a different class) preferable with an example.

My Navigation Menu can route the user to two pages "Home Page" , "Profile Page".

Supposing the user moves first to the "Home Page" from the "Authentication Page" after Successful Google SignIn. Then user uses the "Navigation Menu" in the "Home Page" to go to the "Profile Page" where he has the option to Sign Out

How do I get Google Sign Out - _handleSignOut() function to work on my Profile Page.

1 . Authentication Page

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;

import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
  String _contactText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleGetContact();
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<Null> _handleGetContact() async {
    setState(() {
      _contactText = "Loading contact info...";
    });
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
          '?requestMask.includeField=person.names',
      headers: await _currentUser.authHeaders,
    );
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      setState(() {
        _contactText = "People API gave a ${response.statusCode} "
            "response. Check logs for details.";
      });
      print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
      return;
    }
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
    final String namedContact = _pickFirstNamedContact(data);
    setState(() {
      if (namedContact != null) {
        _contactText = "I see you know $namedContact!";
      } else {
        _contactText = "No contacts to display.";
      }
    });
  }

  String _pickFirstNamedContact(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<dynamic> connections = data['connections'];
    final Map<String, dynamic> contact = connections?.firstWhere(
      (dynamic contact) => contact['names'] != null,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    if (contact != null) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> name = contact['names'].firstWhere(
        (dynamic name) => name['displayName'] != null,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (name != null) {
        return name['displayName'];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<Null> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _handleSignOut() async {
    _googleSignIn.disconnect();
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (_currentUser != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: _currentUser,
            ),
            title: Text(_currentUser.displayName),
            subtitle: Text(_currentUser.email),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          Text(_contactText),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('REFRESH'),
            onPressed: _handleGetContact,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text("You are not currently signed in."),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
            onPressed: _handleSignIn,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        )
        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigator(),
      );
  }
}
```

2 . Home Page

```
import  'package:streaming_entertainment/movie_detail_navigation.dart';

class   HomePage    extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState    createState()   =>  new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  } 

  Widget welcomeMessage(){
    return new Container(
      width: 100.0,
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new Text(
          "This is the the Home Page",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 3,                  
          textScaleFactor: 1.0                              
        ),
      ),                
    );
  }                   

  Widget homeUI(){
    return new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,                    
      children: [
        welcomeMessage(),
      ],
    ); 
  }


  @override
  Widget    build(BuildContext context) {       

    return  new Scaffold(      
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: new Container(
        child   : new   Center(             
          child : homeUI(),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigator(),
        );
  }
}
```

2 . Profile Page

```
class   ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProfilePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState()   =>  new _ProfilePageState();
}

    class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {


      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      } 

      _signOutFromGoogle() async {
        // Google Sign Out 
      }

      Widget welcomeMessage(){
        return new Container(
          width: 100.0,
          child: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: new Text(
              "This is the the Profile Page",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 3,                  
              textScaleFactor: 1.0                              
            ),
          ),                
        );
      }   

      Widget logoutButton(){
        return new FlatButton(
          onPressed: (){
            _signOutFromGoogle();
          },
          child: new Text('Sign Out'),
        );
      }               

      Widget profileUI(){
        return new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,                    
          children: [
            welcomeMessage(),
            logoutButton(),
          ],
        ); 
      }


      @override
      Widget    build(BuildContext context) {       

        return  new Scaffold(      
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          body: new Container(
            child   : new   Center(             
              child : profileUI(),
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigator(),
            );
      }
    }
```

2 . Bottom Navigation Bar

```
class   BottomNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomNavigator({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavigatorState createState()   =>  new _BottomNavigatorState();
}

class _BottomNavigatorState extends State<BottomNavigator> {

  Widget navigationOptions(String imageUrl, var route, String optionName){ 
    return new Container(
      height: 40.0,
      child: new GestureDetector(
        child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),          
            child: new Image.asset(
              imageUrl,
              color: Colors.black,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 20.0,
              height: 20.0,                                                     
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),          
              child: new Text(
                optionName,
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                textScaleFactor: 0.75,  
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),        
        onTap: (){
          print ("Move to Selected Page");         
          Navigator.of(context).push(route);
        },
      ),
    ); 
  }

  Widget universalNavigationBar(){
    var routeHome = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomePage());
    var routeProfile = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new ProfilePage());
    return new BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.white, // new Color(0xFFFFB500)
      child: new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            navigationOptions("images/home.png", routeHome, "home"),
            navigationOptions("images/profile.png", routeProfile, "profile"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget    build(BuildContext  context)    {
    return universalNavigationBar();
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented google sign in with firebase and it is similar to what you are looking for.
So you can refer this:

main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'details.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final  GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  static bool _LoginButton = true;
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

  void signOut(){
    googleSignIn.signOut();
    setState((){
      _LoginButton = true;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
    print(_LoginButton);
    print("User Signed Out");
  }


  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async{
    if(_LoginButton==true){
      setState((){
        _LoginButton=false;
      });
      GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
      firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithGoogle(idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken, accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
      print("Username is "+firebaseUser.displayName);
      setState((){
        _LoginButton = true;
      });

      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => details(firebaseUser.displayName,signOut)));
      return firebaseUser;
    }
  }

  bool _LoginButtonBool(){
    return _LoginButton;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Google auth with firebase"),),
      body: Center(
        child: _LoginButtonBool()?Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(onPressed: _LoginButtonBool() ? () => _signIn().then((FirebaseUser firebaseuser ) =>print(firebaseuser)).catchError((e) => print(e)): null,
              child: Text("Login"),color: Colors.orange,),
            ],
          ),
        ):CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent.withOpacity(0.01),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

details.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class details extends StatefulWidget {

  String name;
  final Function callback;
  details(this.name,this.callback);

  @override
  _detailsState createState() => _detailsState(name,callback);
}

class _detailsState extends State<details> {
  String name;
  final Function callback;
  _detailsState(this.name,this.callback);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Center(child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(name),
          MaterialButton(onPressed: () => callback(),
              child: Text("Log out"),color: Colors.orange),
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But what do I do when I have already popped MyHomePage from my Navigation Stack - what must I do to handle signOut when it's on my drawer menu which can be accessed by any other page

Comment: Your code in above question don't use any kind of drawer so i am unable to understand your problem. Can you please update your code above so i can understand your problem well.

Comment: I've edited the question and provided more code, I hope I've made my question more understandable

Answer (score 0):

**I Implement Like this and it solves one crucial problem i.e. auto log in into previously used google account.**

*BTW I use both google and email/password authentication for my project.*

```
class HomeDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomeDrawer({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<HomeDrawer> createState() => _HomeDrawerState();
    }
    
    class _HomeDrawerState extends State<HomeDrawer> {
      bool _isGoogleAuth = false;

      void outputProviderID() {

        String providerId;

        // get the current user
        User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

        // check if user is not null
        if (user != null) {
          // iterate over each provider data
          for (UserInfo info in user.providerData) {
            providerId = info.providerId;
            if (providerId == 'google.com') {
              setState(() {
                _isGoogleAuth = true;
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        outputProviderID();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Drawer(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                
    
                // log out
                DrawerButton(
                  buttonText: 'Log Out',
                  buttonIcon: const FaIcon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt,
                    size: 20,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  buttonFunction: () {
                    if (_isGoogleAuth) {
                      GoogleSignIn().disconnect().then(
                            (value) => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
                          );
                    } else {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    }
                  },
                ),



              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

You can add `try{}catch(e){}` block to handle errors.